# Power Bi: Link Tables

Tags: powerbi

In power bi, I have a table `Customer` in which I am keeping the Id, name and other details of customer. I have another table named `Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping` which contains CustomerId and its CustomerRoleId. I have another table name `CustomerRoles` which contains name and id of each role.

`CustomerRoles` and `Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping` are linked together.

In Power Bi, I want to show customers count role wise in a pie chart? I tried but I am unable to apply linkage between these tables. I am new to Power Bi.

Comment: Did you link `Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping` and `Customer` also?

Comment: @NickyvV Yes. I have linked them as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Tables:

- Customer
- Role
- CustomerInRole

The Table "Customer" is not necessary for your Report because you only need to know the count of rows in "CustomerInRole" per row in "Role". So just add a pie chart, use the name of the role in the axis (or legend) and the (distinct) count of Field "CustomerIDs" in "CustomerInRole"

That is all you need ;-)

Answer (score 1):

please find table relation  is one-way or two-way  . if it is complex and you are going for two way then it will not show.

Comment: it is one-way table.

Answer (score 0):

To have things clear I would add the role to your customer's table. There's no use in keeping things in a relational way when you start playing with BI.

This can easily be done in the query editor. On the home tab, click "Edit Queries"
[image: Edit Queries]

And there you'll have to click "Merge queries", also on the home tab completely on the right. 
[image: Merge queries]

In the upper table you select the CustomerID-column and Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping table, select the right ID for that table. After clicking "Ok" you can expand the new columns (by right clicking the merged query-column). You will have to repeat this step to add the roles to the Customer table, but in this second round you will have to work with selectint the roleId's.

After all this you can delete the columns that you don't need anymore from this table and just keep the role.

In the pie chart you then just add the role and select "Count".

It is handy to solve it like this when you have other Fact-tables, and you want to use Role as a Dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You can be linking of tables in power bi desktop go dashboard and click on the third  menu as showing in  image [Relation Management data table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KSS2.png) whatever you want make relation with table just drag and drop to link within multiple and single tables with parent and child tables and if you want to delete this relation just go on relation arrow(line) do right click on line and delete it and save file.
Cheers.